# Very strange behaviour in new/free

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I've run into a strange problem. The `Release` version of my application seems to run fine, but recently when I switched to the `Debug` version, I got an access violation immediately on start-up. The access violation is occurring when a block of allocated memory is freed. All of this occurs in the constructor for a static variable.

I believe the problem doesn't occur in the `Release` version simply because I have defined `NDEBUG` there, which I believe disables assertions in the C runtime.

I've been able to narrow things down a bit. If I add the following code to the constructor before the usual calls, then I get the same error:

```
int *temp = new int[3];
delete[] temp;
```

This makes me think that something outside of this block of code is causing the problem, e.g., perhaps there is a problem with the way the C runtime is being linked. However, I'm at a loss to say what that problem might be, and after a day of poking at the problem I'm running out of ideas for where to poke next.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Visual Studio 2010 to compile the application and running Windows 7.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The two lines of code you wrote are legal and perfectly fine. There must be something specific to your code. If it is small enough to do so, could you post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Global static variables with complex constructors is asking for trouble. Look up singletons.

Comment: You might want to try using pageheap to see if it shows up problems in your release build.

Comment: Unfortunately the application is a few hundred thousand lines of code, and I have not been able to reproduce the problem in a smaller test application. That's part of the reason why I'm wondering if there might be some mistake I'm making in linking the C runtime, for example.

Comment: I will try modifying this part of the code to use the singleton pattern and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: Bad news. The global static variable isn't used during start-up, so I thought I would eliminate it temporarily to see what happens. When it is eliminated, start-up continues to the application's ```InitInstance``` function, right up to the point where I first use ```delete[]```, then it crashes in the same way as before. It looks like the problem is not caused by the specific variable that was being freed, but rather by a problem with the ```delete[]``` call itself. This is why I'm wondering if it's possible to wind up with a corrupt C runtime.

Comment: A bit more news... I've submitted an answer to my own question below giving the details, but briefly it looks like I may have been right in my initial suspicion about issues with linking the C runtime. I've sent an email to the vendor whose library seems to be at the root of the problem, and will let you all know if we manage to find a solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In Debug mode, additional checks are added; therefore it's not unusual for a program to run perfectly well in Release mode but to give an access violation in Debug mode. This doesn't mean that the Release version is OK; it only means that some error made when the Release version is running is not catched but is when running in Debug mode.

Debugging a corrupted memory problem in C/C++ is very hard because the error can be made by any other instruction affecting the memory.  For example, if you have two arrays that follow one each other in the allocated memory and the first array is overrun, then it will corrupt the header put before the second array (each memory allocation is prefixed by an header; this header is used by the operators delete and delete[] when deallocating the memory).  However, only when you will try to deallocate the second array that the access violation will occurs and this, even if it's with the first array that there is error in the code.

Of course, you can have other problems with the second array.  For example, you can find that some or all of its values have been corrupted when trying to read from it.  However, it's not always the case and in many occasions, it might behave perfectly well when reading or writing to or from it and you can have the exact same good behavior with the first array.  It's not because you don't have any problem reading and writing to and from some array that you don't overstep its boundary and corrupting the memory above (or below) it.  Sometimes, the problem will only show up when trying to deallocate the array and other  times, the problem will show up otherwise; for example with the display of corrupted values.

Comment: I've dealt with access violations before that were as you describe, but what seems strange to me this time is that I get the same problem even with the simple test shown in the original post. The two calls are literally one after the other, which makes me think it is unlikely (though not impossible) that the array would be corrupted in between.

Comment: I've added a bit more information in a comment above, but thought I would reproduce it here. I eliminated the variable which was causing problems before, since it isn't used until well after the application has started. Now the same problem occurs with the very first call do ```delete[]``` in the ```InitInstance``` function during start-up. My best guess right now is that the call to ```delete[]``` somehow isn't resulting in a valid call in the C runtime, but I'm not sure how that would happen.

Comment: Maybe but if the memory is already corrupted, anything that is done with it after that could result in an access violation and this, even if the following calls are perfectly valid. You have said it yourself that you cannot reproduce the problem in a smaller test application.  You should look at a way of testing and/or verifiying the use of pointers and of memory allocation/deallocation in your application; for example by counting them when the program is running; by adding a marker at then end of any array; by making sure that the operators delete and delete[] are never mixed up, etc., etc.

Comment: Thanks! I did manage to reproduce the problem in a minimal application eventually. I've submitted an answer to my own question below describing the results. I've sent an email to the vendor whose library seems to be causing the problem, and will report back if we are able to come to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce a minimal example by cutting away essentially all of my application code. I reduced the `InitInstance` function to the following:

```
BOOL CTempApp::InitInstance()
{
    int *temp = new int[3] ;
    delete[] temp ;

    return FALSE ;
}
```

Even with all of my application code stripped away, the problem persisted. After this, I created a new project in Visual Studio 2010, once again replaced `InitInstance` with my minimal version, and then added all of the `Additional Dependencies` from my original project in the linker options. With this configuration, the problem was reproduced.

Next, I started removing libraries from the list of dependencies. I managed to whittle the list down to a single third-party library which was causing the following linker warning despite being labeled as the debug version:

```
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrtd.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

I think what's happening here is that the vendor has linked his debug library against the non-debug runtime. Presumably when my application calls `delete[]` there is some confusion as to what the parameters are for the call, and it is trying to delete a portion of memory I have not allocated.

I have tried adding the following to my `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` list:

```
libc.lib, libcmt.lib, msvcrt.lib, libcd.lib, libcmtd.lib
```

as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0.aspx). However, the problem persists. I think the solution will be to contact the vendor and have them resolve the conflict.

Thanks again for your suggestions. I hope this answer will help someone else with debugging a similar problem.

Comment: Searching for msvcrtd.lib show many problems with this library and in particular, the following notice from https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/msvcrtd.libcinitexe.obj_warning_lnk4098_defaultlib_msvcrt.lib_conflicts_wit : "This happens because Qt is linked against the release version of the C runtime
 and your application is built with debug symbols. You need to rebuild Qt in
 debug mode or the application in release mode".

Comment: That's what I'm thinking... The vendor offers separate release and debug versions of their library, but it looks like a release dependency has made its way into their debug library. I told the vendor that they most likely compiled their library or one of its dependent libraries using the ```/MD``` flag instead of ```/MDd```.